# Why ?: operator does not work with nullable<int> assignation?

Tags: c#, .net, operators

I'm creating an object for my database and I found a weird thing, which I don't understand:

I've an object which should reference a "language" by an ID, but this can be null, so my property is a `int?(Nullable<int>)`

so firstly I tried to use the object initializer:

```
myObject = new MyObject() 
{
    myNullableProperty = language == null ? null : language.id;
}
```

but it doesn't work! It tell me that null cannot be converted to `int`

But if I it in a `if/else` structure, I can put null in a var and then assign it to my properties.

Why is this acting like this?

Comment: Your code won't compile due to syntax error - if it's copy/paste error please correct it by editing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may try casting the `null` to `int?` as the `?:` operator requires both operands to return the same type:

```
myNullableProperty = language == null ? (int?)null : language.id
```

Comment: You could also cast (or lift, or wrap) the other "side" af the colon, like this: `language == null ? null : (int?)language.id`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of a type mismatch. You must cast your null value to the int type.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, when using the `?` operator the left and the right side of the `:` are required to be from the same type and `typeof(null)!=typeof(int)` so:

```
myNullableProperty = language == null ? (int?)null : language.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely null is interpreted as object which obviously can't be assigned to int. You might want to use `myNullableProperty = language == null ? (int?)null : language.id;`

Comment: Okay, but why if I do it in a if(language==null){languageId = null;}else{...} is working?